# How to create resource for service using Corosync/Pacemaker

Tags: pacemaker, corosync, vmware-vcloud-director

Am new to serverfault, hoping to see the experts answers for my query.

I have done a Active/passive setup for 1 cell vCloud Director. Below are the setup details.

- OS : CentOS 7.10
- vCloud Director : 9.5
- DRBD9.0 : For data replication between 2 nodes
- Corosync & Pacemaker : For heartbeat and resource creation.

Below is the cluster details : After creating resource VCD-SERVICE for service vmware-vcd, am getting below failed action and cluster goes into no responsive mode even if i restart pacemaker.

Resource created with this command:

`pcs resource create VCD-SERVICE lsb:vmware-vcd op monitor interval=15s`

Experts valuable input is highly appreciated & thanks in advance.

```text
# pcs status
Cluster name: VCD_Cluster
Stack: corosync
Current DC: app1 (version 1.1.19-8.el7_6.2-c3c624ea3d) - partition with quorum
Last updated: Wed Jan  9 07:11:40 2019
Last change: Wed Jan  9 06:52:26 2019 by root via cibadmin on app2

2 nodes configured
5 resources configured

Online: [ app1 ]
OFFLINE: [ app2 ]

Full list of resources:

 VCD_VIP        (ocf::heartbeat:IPaddr2):       Started app1
 Master/Slave Set: VCDClone [VCD-DRBD]
     Masters: [ app1 ]
     Stopped: [ app2 ]
 VCD_FS (ocf::heartbeat:Filesystem):    Started app1
 VCD-SERVICE    (lsb:vmware-vcd):        ORPHANED FAILED app2 (blocked)

Failed Actions:
* VCD-SERVICE_monitor_0 on app1 'not installed' (5): call=18, status=Not installed, exitreason='',
    last-rc-change='Wed Jan  9 07:09:33 2019', queued=1ms, exec=1ms
* VCD-SERVICE_stop_0 on app2 'not configured' (6): call=21, status=complete, exitreason='',
    last-rc-change='Wed Jan  9 07:14:32 2019', queued=0ms, exec=28ms


Daemon Status:
  corosync: active/enabled
  pacemaker: active/enabled
  pcsd: active/enabled
```

Refer image for VCD-SERVICE details[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iZs0P.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want to define the `VCD-SERVICE` with the `systemd` class instead of `lsb`.

LSB init scripts must be located in `/etc/init.d`, and must comply with LSB exit codes to be used with Pacemaker. In CentOS 7, most services are controlled by `systemd`.

EDIT 1: Here is a link to LSB spec:
http://refspecs.linuxbase.org/LSB_3.0.0/LSB-PDA/LSB-PDA/iniscrptact.html

and another link to the Linux-HA.org wiki to check for compliance:
http://www.linux-ha.org/wiki/LSB_Resource_Agents

It's usually pretty easy to edit an init script to make it LSB compliant, but you can also write an OCF resource agent for Pacemaker. A quick Google for, "OCF Pacemaker resource agent development" should bring up some good resources.

Comment: Dear Matt, thank you for your input, yes i have tried using systemd class but pacemaker is not identifying that as service, do you know how to create the resource for service using pcs.